Yolov8 bbox decoding
From image bellow (taken from here), we can see that bbox output in yolov8 has size 4 x reg_max. In yolov8 implementation, the reg_max is set to 16 (16 predicted bboxes) so the output has size 64.
How the final bbox is computed from the 16 proposals?


As I understand, this task is performed by the non-maximum suppression (NMS) process.

A technique to filter the predictions of object detectors. Input: A list of Proposal boxes B, corresponding confidence scores S and
overlap threshold N. Output: A list of filtered proposals D.
https://towardsdatascience.com/non-maximum-suppression-nms-93ce178e177c

In predict.py ultralytics module:
def postprocess(self, preds, img, orig_imgs):
    """Post-processes predictions and returns a list of Results objects."""
    preds = ops.non_max_suppression(
            preds,
            self.args.conf,
            self.args.iou,
            agnostic=self.args.agnostic_nms,
            max_det=self.args.max_det,
            classes=self.args.classes,
        )
    # ... the rest of method logic

In ops.py ultralytics module:
def non_max_suppression(
    prediction,
    conf_thres=0.25,
    iou_thres=0.45,
    classes=None,
    agnostic=False,
    multi_label=False,
    labels=(),
    max_det=300,
    nc=0,  # number of classes (optional)
    max_time_img=0.05,
    max_nms=30000,
    max_wh=7680,
    in_place=True,
    rotated=False,
):
    """
    Perform non-maximum suppression (NMS) on a set of boxes, 
    with support for masks and multiple labels per box.
    Returns:
        (List[torch.Tensor]): A list of length batch_size, where each element is a tensor of
        shape (num_boxes, 6 + num_masks) containing the kept boxes, with columns
        (x1, y1, x2, y2, confidence, class, mask1, mask2, ...).
"""
    # ... the rest of method logic


I don't think so. If you look at this image ("https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:640/format:webp/1*SCXkG5UwsLUlKuF7lEQ4-A.png"), you can clearly see that NMS is used after the transformation from size 64 to 4 (from 16 bbox proposals to the final one). It's related to the focal loss distribution, but I don't know how to calculate the final bbox from the distribution during the inference.

Now I see. Have you looked over the head module?https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/nn/modules/head.py
